# Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous - Recommendation System

Tags: sql, ambiguous

I'm trying to get Products listed where the occupationID matches an occupationID on my table Accounts and keep getting the above error.

```
SELECT productID, productName, productDesc, productImgPath, 
       productPrice, catID, occupationID, Accounts.occupationID  
FROM Products 
JOIN Accounts ON occupationID = Accounts.occupationID 
WHERE occupationID = Accounts.occupationID
```

Comment: "FROM Products JOIN Accounts ON occupationID = Accounts.occupationID" fully qualify all of the elements in your join. It is getting confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you have no 'id' column - I think you just need to fully qualify your statement;

```
SELECT productID, productName, productDesc, productImgPath, 
       productPrice, catID, occupationID, Accounts.occupationID  
FROM Products 
JOIN Accounts ON Products.occupationID = Accounts.occupationID
```

You no longer need the WHERE as it's doing the same as the join

```
WHERE Products.occupationID = Accounts.occupationID
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because occupationId is ambiguous being in both Products and accounts.
Fully qualify the field.

```
    SELECT productID, productName, productDesc, productImgPath, productPrice, P.catID, P.occupationID, A.occupationID
    FROM Products P JOIN Accounts A ON P.occupationID = A.occupationID
```

Note: your WHERE clause is redundant because it's taken care of in the join.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any `id` column in your query, but i would suggest to use `alise` that could be easier to read and write.

```
SELECT p.productID, p.productName, p.productDesc, p.productImgPath, 
       p.productPrice, a.catID, p.occupationID, a.occupationID  
FROM Products p -- use of alise p instead of table_name
INNER JOIN Accounts a ON p.occupationID = a.occupationID 
--WHERE occupationID = Accounts.occupationID (redundant where clause)
```

Please review the column selection and use exact or correct table alise instead.